Page breaks when zooming in
My website is displayed as intended at 100% zoom + when zoomed out. However, a problem occurs once you zoom in. It initially looks fine, but after navigating to the right side of the page, all the elements on the right are cut off, leaving a black gap. Only the horizontal navigation bar works fine.
(Another issue is that I cannot scroll to the left, only to the right (once zoomed). I assume this could be a problem with the contents, menu-vertical and wrapper being a flexbox element, seeing as the scrolling starts where the vertical menu begins.)
I don't want the elements to behave like flexboxes when zooming in, I want zoom similar to this website.
My code snippet:
.menu-horizontal { grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 4;
margin:0 auto; 
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; 

  min-width: 1450px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-horizontal nav ul { 
  list-style: none;
    font-size:0;
}

.menu-horizontal-bg { grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 4;
 background-image: url('assets/horizontal-nav-bg2.png');
  background-size: auto;
    background-position: center; 
 margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
 max-width: 1850px;
      margin: 0 auto;
 height: 58px;
 z-index: -2;
}

.menu-horizontal li { 
  display: inline-flex;
}

.menu-horizontal li a { 
  font-size:16px;
  color: #fff; 
    height:69px;
    line-height:69px;
    text-align:center;
    width:160px;

    background-image: url(assets/button.png);
      text-decoration: none;
           position: relative;
}

.hornav-button-left {
        margin-right: -46px;
}

.hornav-button-right {
           margin-left: -6px;
}

.header { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 4;
    background-image: url('assets/header6.png');
    background-size: auto;
    background-position: center;

    margin-bottom: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
 max-width: 1850px;
      margin: 0 auto;
}

.background { grid-area: 3 / 1 / 5 / 4; 


background-image: url('assets/frbg3.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top center;
background-attachment: fixed;
}

.contents {
    grid-area: 3 / 1 / 5 / 4;
     display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;

margin: 57px auto 0;
margin-bottom: 80px;

}

.menu-vertical {
grid-area : 3 / 1 / 5 / 4;
position : relative;
box-sizing : border-box;
padding-left : 48px;
padding-right : 58px;
padding-bottom : 20px;
max-width : 290px;
border-width : 30px 0;
border-image : url(assets/border.png) stretch;
border-image-outset : 13px 5px 13px 4px;
border-image-slice : 66 16 66 0;
border-style : solid;
background-image : url(assets/contentsbgsmall.png);
background-repeat : repeat;
background-size : contain;
} 

.wrapper {
    grid-area: 3 / 2 / 5 / 4;
    max-width: 980px;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    padding-left: 59px;
    padding-right: 59px;

     word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    text-align: justify;

    border-width: 42px 0; 
    border-image: url(assets/border.png) stretch;
    border-image-outset: 25px 18px 25px 18px; 
    border-image-slice: 66 16 66 0; 
    border-style: solid;

 background-image: url(assets/contentsbg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: auto; 
}

Here is the codepen.
The header image, background image and the wrapper image are all cut off on the right side (at zoom). The image behind the horizontal menu disappears altogether (.menu-horizontal-bg).
I tried changing the width of elements to be consistent, but it did not fix my issue. I'm not sure what could be wrong.

I tried replicating this in Stackblitz and it works exactly fine!

thank you for your response, unfortunately i still see the problem in your example. i tried checking through different browsers and it's the same thing
https://imgur.com/Llq1T6U > this part here
